# Failure adding C++ libraries

Tags: c++, qt, dll, taglib

I prepare TagLib for use in my TagLib project as follows:

### Windows 10

1. Build the Makefiles:

   1. Open CMake GUI.
   2. Set Paths.
        "Where is the source code" and "Where to build the binaries"
        Example, Both would be: C:\GitRoot\taglib
   3. Tick: Advanced
   4. Select: Configure
   5. Select: Generator
   6. Tick: Use default native compilers
   7. Select: Finish
      Wait until done.
   8. If using ZLib, Scroll down.
        (to the bottom of the list of options ... should go over them all)

      1. Edit: ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR
      2. Edit: ZLIB_LIBRARY
   9. Select: Generate
2. Build the project:
      MinGW:
        C:\GitRoot\taglib> gmake
3. Install the project:
      MinGW:
        C:\GitRoot\taglib> gmake install

I copy the above generated files into my Taglib project on Qt, so that now this is my **taglibtest project** folder structure:

[image]

then add the following files to my project:

**F:***\taglibtest\taglib\lib\libtag.dll.a**
**F:***\taglibtest\taglib\lib\libtag_c.dll.a**

as you can see below in *tablibtest.pro*

**taglibtest.pro**

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = taglibtest
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/lib/ -llibtag.dll
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/lib/ -llibtag.dlld

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/taglib/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/lib/ -llibtag_c.dll
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/lib/ -llibtag_c.dlld

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/taglib/include

HEADERS += \
    taglib/include/taglib/aifffile.h \
    taglib/include/taglib/aiffproperties.h \
    etc.... \
    etc.... \
    etc....
```

In the main:

```
**main.cpp**

    #include <QCoreApplication>
    #include <QDebug>

    #include <taglib/include/taglib/fileref.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        TagLib::FileRef f("E:/Dire Straits - Sultans of Swing.mp3");
        return a.exec();
    }
```

I get the following error when I run the project:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -llibtag.dll
:-1: error: cannot find -llibtag_c.dll
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing in my project? Which files should I include in my project to use the **Taglib Framework**

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think, in windows, you should link libtag.lib instead of libtag.dll.

Comment: That code is automatically generated by Qt. I used Qt to add the libs: `project -> right click -> Add library`